# Docker compose: can not connect to external port

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose

How looks my docker compose:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  app-1:
    build: docker/.
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/app-1

  app-2:
    build: docker/.
    ports:
      - 8080:8090
    volumes:
      - .:/app-2
```

My problem: i can not connect to external docker port.

When i have ports *'8090:8090'* for app-2 i connect successfully to my application.

But when i am using *'8080:8090'* i can not connect to it.

Could you give me an advice where could be reason?

The app-1 have **server.port=8080**

The app-2 have **server.port=8090**

Comment: Can you try to rename the second service from `app-1` to `app-2`?

Comment: @ddegasperi sorry, just missed it during description writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why the same ports are specified for both of your apps, you can't run 2 apps on same port, so they must be different f.e.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  app-1:
    build: docker/.
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/app-1

  app-2:
    build: docker/.
    ports:
      - 8081:8090
    volumes:
      - .:/app-2
```

[Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to map the same port `8080` to 2 different services, the operation system won't allow it, a listening port can have only one service.

Comment: could you please share documentation link about it?